# Can't access a custom dependency property in a custom control template

Tags: wpf

I created two new properties to a custom button. However, when I try to access it on the template button, the VS says that "the member is not recognized or is not accessible".

**MyButton.cs**

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
   public partial class MyButton : Button, IOperacoesComponentes
   {

       public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Icon", typeof(string),
           typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
       public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string),
           typeof(MyButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

       public MyButton()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       public string Icon
       {
           get { return (string)GetValue(IconProperty); }
           set { SetValue(IconProperty, value); }
       }

       public string Text
       {
           get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
           set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
       }

  ...

  }
```

}

In MyButton.xaml file, when try to access them:

**MyButton.xaml**

```
<Button x:Class="myNameSpace.myButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">

<Button.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="myButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" ClipToBounds="True">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="4" BorderBrush="transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0088D9" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF007BC4" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="content" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
                            <Run Text="{TemplateBinding Icon}"/>
                            <Run Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Button.Resources>
```

The two new properties "Icon" and "Text" appear without problems. But when I try to access them through the "TemplateBiding", VS gives the error message described above.

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Target type must be `MyButton`, not `Button`.

```
<Button.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="MyButton" x:Key="myButton">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyButton}">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Laith. But, in fact, I'm still experiencing an error: VS says 'myButton' ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type 'Button'. But myButton class is derived from Button.

Comment: I see. You're actually creating a `UserControl`. This is not how you should inherit from `Button`. You should google how to create "custom controls in WPF". Your dependency properties will not work in the example you have above.